# накопление вызовов корутин

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть такая реализация: переходы три перехода между играми, когда мы перешли, срабатывает некий метод с корутиной в 3 секунды, но если очень быстро переходить по играм, то корутины накапливаются и метод вызывается подряд, как это собственно можно исправить?

Comment: не запускать более одной, т.е. отменять неактуальную при вызове нового перехода

Comment: точно, спасибо, это решило проблему

Comment: оформил как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо не запускать более одной корутины одновременно, т.е. отменять неактуальную при вызове нового перехода

```
private IEnumerator coroutine;    
private bool changeLevelInProgress;

public IEnumerator ChangeLevelCoroutine() {
    changeLevelInProgress = true;
    ...
    changeLevelInProgress = false;
}

void ChangeLevel() {
    if (changeLevelInProgress)
        StopCoroutine(coroutine);
    coroutine = new ChangeLevelCoroutine();
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);
}
```